# google glass mirror quickstart on drupal with IIS

Tags: google-app-engine, iis, drupal-7, google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have been trying repeatedly to run one of the mirror-quickstart packages off of my drupal website with little luck. I have been working with the java and .NET versions and have gotten both to work great when I run them off of localhost. However, when I try to move it to a page on my site I get the following errors

for the java application I go to www.mywebsite.com/Glassjava. I get redirected to www.mywebsite.com/oauth2callback with the following error:

Page not found

The requested page "/oauth2callback" could not be found.

For the .NET application I go to www.mywebsite.com/DN_glass. I get redirected to www.mywebsite.com/DN_glass/auth and get the error:

Page not found

The requested page "/DN_glass/auth" could not be found.

I have had success running the java off of localhost from a machine running IIS express after specifying the absolute path of the oauth.properties file and following these java servlet instructions: http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/

However, I have not gotten it to work on my drupal site. I don't understand the errors /oauth2callback and /auth. I am pretty sure I don't need to create any such directories and I also think that the oauth.properties file is getting read in order to communicate with the google api console and find the redirect URI (at least in the case of the java error). Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions about using the quickstarts with drupal and iis would also be appreciated.